Reference request: regularity of non-divergence form elliptic operators with Neumann boundary conditions
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth open bounded subset. Consider the second order elliptic operator written in non-divergence form:
\begin{equation}
Lu=a^{i j} D_{ij}u+b^i D_iu+cu
\end{equation}
In Krylov's Lectures on Elliptic and Parabolic Equations in Sobolev Spaces Theorem 9.2.3 page 189, it is stated that:
if $u \in W^{2}_p(\Omega)$ satisfies a Dirichlet Boundary Condition and the coefficients $a^{ij},b^i,c \in C^k(\Omega)$ then $u \in W^{k+2}_p (\Omega)$ and satisfies an inequality of the type $$\|u \|_{W^{k+2}_p} \leq C \left(\|Lu \|_{W^{k}_p} + \|u\|_{L^p} + \text{term due to boundary condition}\right).$$
Note that the condition on the leading coefficient $a^{ij}$ is relaxed by one degree of differentiation less than usual since the operator is in non divergence form.
I am looking for a similar result for Neumann Boundary Conditions?

I want to thank those who have already provided answers. After some time, I think I have found exactly what I was looking for, and I am posting an answer for others who may have the same question in the future.
Results for Neumann boundary conditions can be found in
Giovanni Maria Troianiello. Elliptic differential equations and obstacle problems.
Specifically, Chapter 3, which in fact treats this kind of elliptic operators for mixed boundary conditions.

I cannot think of an immediate ref that covers the material.
However, Gilbarg and Trudinger has a dedicated chapter (Chapter 9) on the strong solutions (to the non-divergence form of second-order elliptic problems). All the estimates are given for Dirichlet problems, yet generalizing from Dirichlet to Neumann is not difficult (yet nontrivial). You can refer to Grisvard Chapter 2 section 2.2.2 to learn how to do it (basically the extension problem from the half-plane needs to be changed).

Here are a couple references that cover general elliptic operators with general boundary conditions.  Of course, they have to be compatible in a certain sense known as the Shapiro-Lopatinski condition in order for the estimates you're after to hold.

Partial Differential Equations by J. Wloka.
Interpolation Theory, Function Spaces, and Differential Operators by H. Triebel.
Non-homogeneous Boundary Value Problems, Vol I by J.L. Lions and E. Magenes.  This only does the case $p=2$, though.

